# Is number of directories in .git/objects is fixed? or it changes based on the number of nodes

Tags: git

Sub-directories in .git/objects/ are named as hexadecimals and info + pack.

Are the number of folders are same always or differs repository to repository.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is not fixed.

Remember "git" is a filesystem before anything else.

There are plenty of good resources, have you looked into them a bit?

- https://git-scm.com/book/en/v2/Git-Internals-Git-Objects
- http://shafiulazam.com/gitbook/1_the_git_object_model.html
- http://www.gitguys.com/topics/the-git-object-model-starting-with-the-blob/